# how to send referer in php code for google client?

Tags: php, google-client-login

As mentioned the error here:

> Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=MYKEY: (403) The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions

My code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("maaa");
    //$client->setHttpClient($httpClient);

    echo "login 2";

    // Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
    // client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
    $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri($callbackurl);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY);
    $client->setAccessType("online");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("auto");
    $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);


       echo "login 3";

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        echo "login inside....";
        try {
            $client->authenticate();
        } catch(Exception $e) {  

            echo $e;
        }

        $token = $client->getAccessToken();

        try {
        $userProfile = $plus->people->get("me");
        }  catch(Exception $e) {  
            //ERROR Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=mYKEY: (403) The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions
            echo $e;
        }

        $id = $userProfile['id'];
        return array(
                'user' => $id,
                'network' => 'google',
                'userprofile' => $userProfile,
                'token' => $token,
                'loginUrl' => null,
                'logoutUrl' => null
        );
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        return array(
                'user' => 0,
                'network' => 'google',
                'userprofile' => $userProfile,
                'token' => null,
                'loginUrl' => $authUrl,
                'logoutUrl' => null
        );
    }
```

Following is the setting for my api. If I keep the below settings then everything works really well but If I wanted to keep the restriction on HTTP then it won't work. If anyone know to make it work without having any issue with the HTTP option then please let me know.
[image]

tHANKS and please let me know if anyone have any idea that how I can send the referer to google client.....

Comment: I have try adding Guzzle through sending referer but it didn't work because of PHP version compatibility. So looking for other solution.

Comment: This is a problem because your have setup referrer limit to your API key but you're not using it in a browser context. I think you can just lift the referrer limit to fix this.

Comment: Thanks but still I wanted to know the way to send referer but I am updating my question with the screenshot of settings set for the apI.

Comment: Because this is not the intended way to use the API Client, I don't think you can directly use the class [Google_Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php). You may subclass it and override its [execute](/src/Google/Client.php#L798-L844) method to add the [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header to the request.